# Чем отличается хранение в памяти массивов из величин значимого и ссылочного типа?

Tags: c#, массивы, память, типы, c#-faq

Чем отличается хранение в памяти массивов из величин значимого и ссылочного типа?

Comment: Идеи есть, но нужен четкий, конкретный и правильный ответ

Comment: @MBo это вопрос, ответ на который может не знать и бывалый программист(например, если не изучал особенности шарпа). Было бы чего посылать в методички. Я считаю что даный вопрос должен быть. Возможно, даже, с тэгом C#Faq и придирки излишни.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Массив - это непрерывная область памяти, в которой последовательно, друг за другом, размещены некоторые элементы. У массива есть заголовок, о котором, обычно, никто не говорит (и не знает), и собственно значения.

Если речь о значимых типах (структурах), они размещаются непосредственно в области выделенной для массива.

В случае ссылочных типов (классов), их экземпляры размещаются в куче, а массив содержит всё те же структуры (IntPtr) - указатели на эти объекты.

В отличии от массива значимых типов, массив ссылочных типом может содержать элементы указывающие на один и тот же объект.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: И сами масивы всегда в .Net являются ссылочным типом независимо от данных, которые в нем хранятся. И размещаются в managed heap.

Comment: @Andrew если мы говорим об управляемых массивах, конечно же. Для неуправляемых есть ```int* array = stackalloc int[100];```

Answer (score 4):

Если отвлечься от специфики именно массивов C# (которые являются ссылочными), то переменная значимого типа хранит непосредственно значение, а переменная ссылочного типа хранит адрес значения. Само значение при этом хранится в динамической памяти (куче).

Answer (score 2):

**Все массивы являются ссылочными типами.**

*Arrays are mechanisms that allow you to treat several items as a single collection. The Microsoft® .NET Common Language Runtime (CLR) supports single-dimensional arrays, multidimensional arrays, and jagged arrays (arrays of arrays). All array types are implicitly derived from System.Array, which itself is derived from System.Object. **This means that all arrays are always reference types** which are allocated on the managed heap, and your app's variable contains a reference to the array and not the array itself.*

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533757/is-int-a-reference-type-or-a-value-type
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/bb985948(v=msdn.10)

Comment: Вопрос не о том

Comment: на *"Stack Overflow на русском"* хотелось бы видеть ответы на русском

Comment: @4per 1сник? дал краткий ответ на русском, развернутый - скопировал с офф сайта(чтобы при переводе не потерять деталей)

Comment: @pashagoroshko, нет не 1сник. Ответы на английском, я и все остальные можем прочесть на enSO.